# OpenMP/C++: number of elements in for-loop

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

I am doing some very simple tests with OpenMP in C++ and I encounter a problem that is probably silly, but I can't find out what's wrong. In the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{

  int nthreads=1, threadid=0;
  clock_t tstart, tend;
  const int nx=10, ny=10, nz=10;
  int i, j, k;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long long int> > > arr_par;

  arr_par.resize(nx);
  for (i=0; i<nx; i++) {
    arr_par[i].resize(ny);
    for (j = 0; j<ny; j++) {
      arr_par[i][j].resize(nz);
    }
  }

  tstart = clock();
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(threadid)
  {
#ifdef _OPENMP
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    threadid = omp_get_thread_num();
#endif
#pragma omp master
    std::cout<<"OpenMP execution with "<<nthreads<<" threads"<<std::endl;
#pragma omp end master
#pragma omp barrier
#pragma omp critical
    {
      std::cout<<"Thread id: "<<threadid<<std::endl;
    }

#pragma omp for
    for (i=0; i<nx; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<ny; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<nz; k++) {
          arr_par[i][j][k] = i*j + k;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  tend = clock();
  std::cout<<"Elapsed time: "<<(tend - tstart)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<" s"<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

if `nx`, `ny` and `nz` are equal to `10`, the code is running smoothly. If I increase these numbers to `20`, I get a segfault. It runs without problem sequentially or with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`, whatever the number of elements.

I compiled the damn thing with

```
g++ -std=c++0x -fopenmp -gstabs+ -O0 test.cpp -o test
```

using GCC 4.6.3.

Any thought would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a data race in your loop counters:

```
#pragma omp for
for (i=0; i<nx; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<ny; j++) {          // <--- data race
    for (k=0; k<nz; k++) {        // <--- data race
      arr_par[i][j][k] = i*j + k;
    }
  }
}
```

Since neither `j` nor `k` are given the `private` data-sharing class, their values might exceed the corresponding limits when several threads try to increase them at once, resulting in out-of-bound access to `arr_par`. The chance to have several threads increase `j` or `k` at the same time increases with the number of iterations.

The best way to treat those cases is to simply declare the loop variables inside the loop operator itself:

```
#pragma omp for
for (int i=0; i<nx; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<ny; j++) {
    for (int k=0; k<nz; k++) {
      arr_par[i][j][k] = i*j + k;
    }
  }
}
```

The other way is to add the `private(j,k)` clause to the head of the parallel region:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(threadid) private(j,k)
```

It is not strictly necessary to make `i` private in your case since the loop variable of parallel loops are implicitly made private. Still, if `i` is used somewhere else in the code, it might make sense to make it private to prevent other data races.

Also, don't use `clock()` to measure the time for parallel applications since on most Unix OSes it returns the total CPU time for all threads. Use `omp_get_wtime()` instead.